# How to execute multiple mklabel commands in a single session of rcleartool in command prompt?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, cleartool

I am trying to execute multiple `mklabel` commands in `rcleartool` from cmd in a batch file.

The commands that I am using are like:

```
echo Server URL | rcleartool mklabel Label_Name Object1
echo Server URL | rcleartool mklabel Label_Name Object2
echo Server URL | rcleartool mklabel Label_Name Object3
.
.
```

It is taking too long to execute each command.
I have tried finding a way for executing the `mklabel` commands in a single `rcleartool` session. But I didn't find any.

How to achieve this in one call instead of 3 (or n)?

Answer (score 0):

If you could list your objects through a [`rcleartool find`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_find.htm), you could have use one `mklabel` in the `-exec` section. Sadly, `-exec` is not supported by `rcleartool` (only `-print`)

[`rlceartool mklabel`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm) supports multiple `pname` though

```
pname ...
```

> (Required) One or more path names, indicating versions to be labeled:
>
> - A standard or view-extended path name to an element specifies the version selected in the view.
> - A version-extended path name specifies a version, independent of view.

That means you should be able to use:

```
echo Server URL | rcleartool mklabel Label_Name Object1 Object2 Object3
```

Depending on the number of files to label, you might want to find them first and assign their list (space separated) to variable, then call `rcleartool mklabel Label_Name %list%`.